# I want to print html to the browser before any process in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to print some html to the browser while process is running so user can not see the blank page in laravel.

I tried following code but this is rendering output to the browser after process completes.

```
        $v = view('users.account_varification',compact('AccessToken'));
        $content = $v->render();
        echo $content;
```

Please help me.

Comment: If you have any long running task, why don't you display the page and then make an ajax request to retrieve all the data?

Comment: I can not use ajax as this is account activation link clickable directly from email.

Comment: That's not an excuse for not being able to use ajax.

Comment: And what you are trying to do is simply not possible.

Comment: use ajax from scratch or something async like https://github.com/spatie/async

Answer (score 0):

I have used following code to show loading while process is going on.
PHP output buffer has limit of 4KB so we can show limited amount of content to the browser while process is going on.

```
        //STARTs - show loading
            // Turn off output buffering
            ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
            // Turn off PHP output compression
            ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);


            //Flush (send) the output buffer and turn off output buffering
            //ob_end_flush();
            while (@ob_end_flush());

            // Implicitly flush the buffer(s)
            ini_set('implicit_flush', true);
            ob_implicit_flush(true);

            ob_start(null, 4096);
            $v = view('users.loading');
            echo $content = $v->render();
            ob_end_flush();
        //ENDs - show loading
```